# Screen goes blank for activity in Android app when re-entering activity

Tags: android, user-interface

I have an activity that contains a listview. When another activity shows this activity, everything works fine and I am able to return back to the first activity. But if I then call that same activity again a short while later, that activity will launch and the code does get executed. I can even see the listview's adapter getting called, so everything seems to be working fine. But once the onCreate completes and listview has completed its job of displaying its items, the screen for that activity goes blank. Even worse, if I press the Back button, I cannot return back to the first activity. My app isn't hung because I do have a service running in the background and can verify that it is still running by placing a breakpoint in it. Also, I can see in Eclipse that the app is still running. So what could be causing the screen to go blank and cause the keyboard to freeze up? I can post the code but it is rather involved and am just looking for clues at the moment.

Comment: Did you finish the activity when going back?

Comment: Without code nobody can predict whats happening there in your application. because it is an unexpected behavior.

@Ramyle: If he finished() the activity when going back he wonl see the black screen, but he will see launcher.

Comment: The activity is finishing.